# image not displaying correctly which i took by using my android app

Tags: java, android, android-camera, motorola, image-formats

created employee face recognition android application, have 2 major part in the app ,register face & record attendance ->while recording attendance using face recognition ,am storing checkin time with chekin faceimage same for checkout, am displaying this checkin faceimage & checkout face in my webapp employee reports page, i tested this app with different devices, for all it working fine using moto g62 getting the image in grayscale format image is not visible, why ? did lot things  by changing the camera settings, display, grayscale, color correction nothing help, can any one tell me what i have to do for this ->do i need to change my android app code or moto mobile camera  setting??

note: ref ss ,this is how am getting my emp face image in the report page[image]

tried to get the correct viewable image format but getting unviewable face image